# how to do Logging & Monitoring on Google Cloud Storage Buckets with IAM user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to create an alerting mechanism for GCS bucket events where users within my organization or my IAM users do anything on Buckets like Downloading, updating, or deleting, any object I should get an alert but I have no idea how I suppose to do this.

So far I have managed to create an alert if a user deletes anything or creates anything I got an alert on my slack channel

but I have no idea how I implement the above mention use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate the audit logs on Cloud Storage (be careful it can generate a lot of logs and then cost a lot, use with caution).

Then you can do what you want with your logs:

- Create a log based metrics and then an alert on that metrics (logs with read, write, delete operation)
- Create a Cloud Logging sink to send messages in PubSub to script the action on each event (send an email, send a slack message,...)
- Create a Cloud Logging sink to BigQuery and perform a periodic query followed by a formatted email with the query result to have a periodic report

Comment: Hi,
I'm able to get these value when I hit the bucket alert but still there is no user name 
although I can get the username by the time I click on the given URL via webhook but I want to print at slack
fetch object
Log match condition fired for GCS Bucket with {bucket_name=monitoring-01, location=us-east1, project_id=oval-precept-363010}.

Comment: Do you mean no user name in the logs?

Comment: in simple words, I want to customize the webhook properties for now the webhook only have three properties
bucket_name=
location=
project_id=

what I want along with this, a username property so when the alert gets triggered I also should get the username value so without opening the URL I'll get to know that this user is trying to access my resource.

Comment: @kingfatehkhan in order to include values in the alert, you need to create labels on the log-based metrics, and then a metric alert instead of a log-based alert. Labels (e.g. your `username`) will then be available under `metric.label.{KEY}` https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/doc-variables

Answer (score 0):

We can interpret the following from the above case:

- Individual A is trying to get notifications for the version
  changes(Creation, Deletion and Updating) and for actions like
  copying, downloading, uploading, etc., of the objects stored in GCS
- Generally it will be within the organization as other parties will be
  restricted from accessing sensitive information stored in the buckets
  but if there are other users apart from within the organization we
  can create filters and send out the notifications.
- Individual A wishes to receive alerts in slack.

There is a [solution](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification) available for this in the GCP official documentation. It clearly explains how to enable notifications, how to filter the content and how to create and use pub/sub topics for sending the notifications. Since the preferred medium is slack, he can use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-notifications/configure-slack) for configuring slack notifications.

Comment: Hi,
I'm able to get these value when I hit the bucket alert but still there is no user name 
although I can get the username by the time I click on the given URL via webhook but I want to print at slack
fetch object
Log match condition fired for GCS Bucket with {bucket_name=monitoring-01, location=us-east1, project_id=oval-precept-363010}.